# How to play facebook embed videos without going to fullscreen on iOS devices?

Tags: html, facebook, video, iframe

I am trying to insert a Facebook embed video on my HTML code. Following is the sample code provided in the Facebook player [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api/).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: "{your-app-id}",
        xfbml: true,
        version: "v3.2"
      });

      // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
      var my_video_player;
      FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.ready", function(msg) {
        if (msg.type === "video") {
          my_video_player = msg.instance;
        }
      });
    };
  </script>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
  <!-- Your embedded video player code -->
  <div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" data-width="500" data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

But on iOS devices, it is playing only in fullscreen mode. Is there a way I can play video without going to fullscreen?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried asking at the Facebook developer forums? Normally you add `playsinline` to your `<video>` tag for non-fullscreen playback. Since you're embedding someone else's player/code then you'll have to check with the official forums if they allow it.